# Multiple Type Inheritance in Ada

Tags: types, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance, ada

Suppose I have the following:

```
type blah is abstract tagged 
record 
element1 : integer; 
end record;

type blah2 is abstract tagged
record
element2 : integer;
end record;
```

I'm hoping that it's possible that I can do something like this:

```
type blah3 is abstract new blah1 and blah 2 with null record;
```

So in theory I can now access blah3.element1 and blah3.element2

Is this possible? and any hints or tips?

UPDATE:

Would it be possible to references the elements of blah3 (containing blah and blah2) using pointers?

I.E. (this is just a rough idea code is terrible...LOL)

```
type blah3 is new type with
record
element1 : ptr to blah.element1;
element2 : ptr to blah2.element2;
end record
```

and are then able to be accessed via
blah3.element1 for example?

Comment: In short, no, multiple inheritance is not possible in Ada in the manner you hope. Close analogues are possible using "mixins" and interface inheritance, but I've not done much in those areas, so I don't want to give advice with no experience to back it up (not that that stops most bloggers :-).

What's the problem you're trying to solve? Maybe there's a good solution that doesn't involve MI.

Comment: The goal is to keep a particlar "package" black boxed, I.E. the record Blah 3 is the typical "call" to our package, but certain events have caused the data we have to be put in two different types, the hope was to somehow unify those, so we can leave the initial call alone and it will still work for outside people trying to call in.-- I hope that made sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marc C is right (as usual).

Direct Multiple inheritance is very controversial even in the languages that support it. There are big issues about what the compiler is supposed to do in some edge cases, like when both parent classes define different versions of the same method or member. It was explicitly **not** allowed in Ada95 when they added inheritance.

So your next question will be "So how do I do what i want to do?"

It depends on what you are trying to achieve by using multiple inheritance. In the worst (most complicated) case you can usually achieve the effect you are looking for with "mixin" inheritance. I *have* done it before, but still I think it is explained best in this AdaIC article: [Ada95 and Multiple Inheritance](http://archive.adaic.com/intro/tech/multin.html) than I could do myself.

Here's a digest:

> Ada 95 supports multiple-inheritance
>   module inclusion (via multiple
>   "with"/"use" clauses),
>   multiple-inheritance
>   "is-implemented-using" via private
>   extensions and record composition, and
>   multiple-inheritance mix-ins via the
>   use of generics, formal packages, and
>   access discriminants.

It appears that Ada 2005 has another easier way to do this ("interfaces"), but I haven't had a chance to try that yet. You can read more about it (including why direct MI is *still* considered bad in Ada) [here](http://www.adaic.org/standards/05rat/html/Rat-2-4.html). I found this example. Again, this will only work if your compiler supports Ada 2005

```
Interfaces can be composed from other interfaces thus 
type Int2 is interface;
...
type Int3 is interface and Int1;
...
type Int4 is interface and Int1 and Int2;
...
```

Comment: I think you have to go the mixin route then. I saw a presentation on it *years* ago and it was pretty slick.

Comment: I think we're going to try the "updated" method first just to see if it works, if it doesn't then I think mixin will have to be the alternate, Thanks for all the help!